# How do peolpe share the same content/layout across pages in WinRT/Metro

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

How do share some general layout and content on all my pages in windows store apps?

Can one define a kind of "masterpage"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned master page equivalent approach, I found a link and just wanted to share. Hope this would give better idea on this.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/3e447ad7-04a0-4e9a-bc57-6b43f78217d1/

Comment: Ye i started doing something like that, just need to get it working properly with the layoutawarepage and such. but seems like the way to go

Answer (score 0):

In a basic sense you define a model that you use to display data. You pass an instance of this model to each page. The controls on each page a re data bound to the model context. So you setup a template of sorts for that data and link that to the controls. its called MVVM. MVVM stands for Model - View - ViewModel. Here are a couple good examples:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/391783/An-Address-Book-Application-Made-in-MVVM-For-Metro

[Navigation design for Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761500)

Comment: I know about MVVM, but what im talking about is a graphical layout that are independent of the ViewModel - I just dont want to copy paste it into all my pages. Thanks anyway. I working on using the <Frame> object right and see if how that turns out.